# AlarmManager not found when change date

Tags: android, date, widget, alarmmanager

I'm created a widget and use AlarmManager to update. In my test, the time to update is 1 second. The code run perfectly. If change code to future also runs, but change date to past, the update stops working.
Is there any solution?
Thanks

```
PendingIntent anIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, 
    new Intent(WidgetViewsFactory.REFRESH_ACTION),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmMgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 
    System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000, anIntent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolve the problem. The solution is create a BroadcastReceiver to listen time or date changes and generate a new alarm.

```
public class DateChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            PendingIntent anIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, 
                new Intent(WidgetViewsFactory.REFRESH_ACTION),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000, anIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml add the following lines:

```
<receiver android:name=".DateChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_SET"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```